# jquery confirm dialog with hyperlinks

Tags: jquery

I have created a confirm dialog using jquery and would like to add a hyperlink into it.

```
        warningString = "<p style='margin-top: 15px;'>Please Verify the following URL is a valid Redirect URL.</p> \n" + redirURL;
        var confModalBtns = {
            'Submit': function() {
                $('#product-order-form').submit();
            },
            'Cancel': function() {
                $("#confirmUrlModal").dialog("close");
                toggleValidationLoader("hide");
            }
        };
        $("#confirmUrlModal").html(warningString);
        $("#confirmUrlModal").dialog("option", "buttons", confModalBtns);
        $("#confirmUrlModal").dialog("open");
```

Essentially the variable redirURL is a valid url and i would like to make it active, clickable, etc.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
warningString = "<p style='margin-top: 15px;'>Please Verify the following URL is a valid Redirect URL.</p> <br/><a href='" + redirURL + "'>" + redirURL + "</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The #confirmUrModal HTML element is going to be the content of the dialog box, and you set the element's innerHTML with html(), so....